# How to allow edit *.Vue component in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Please I have not work with Vue before, please can anyone help me?  I have Laravel code  with Vue. I want to edit *.vue component such as navbar.vue  but when add or remove anything and save there is no action in html (in browser)

Comment: You have to transpile it before any changes can be viewed. You can transpile it by running `npm run dev`. (That's assuming you have already run `npm install`). You can also use `npm run watch` to have it watch for file changes and automatically transpile for you.

Comment: ok think you all i solved  it

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure `webpack` to compile you vue files. If its already install, then do `npm run watch` to compile vue files to see your changes